# Data fetching from database using vuejs in laravel 8

Tags: database, laravel, vue.js

I am trying to fetch data from database using vuejs (in laravel 8 framework ). But it yields no data, no error either. I am sharing some screenshots and codes here :

**View**

[image]

**Database**

[image]

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/','App\Http\Controllers\vuecrud@index');

Route::post('/app/add_data','App\Http\Controllers\adminController@addTag');

Route::get('/app/get_data','App\Http\Controllers\adminController@show');

Route::any('{slug}','App\Http\Controllers\vuecrud@index');
```

**AdminController**

```
public function show()
{  
   
   return admin::all();
   
}
```

**admin(model)**

```
class admin extends Model
    {
        //use HasFactory;
        protected $fillable = ['tagName'];
    }
```

**app.js(inside js floder)**

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue')
import router from './router'
import ViewUI from 'view-design';
import 'view-design/dist/styles/iview.css';
import common from './common'
Vue.mixin(common)

Vue.use(ViewUI);

('mainapp', require('./components/mainapp.vue').default)
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router
})
```

**router.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
Vue.use(Router)
import firstPage from './components/pages/firstvuepage'
import aboutpage from './components/pages/aboutus'
import admin from './components/pages/admin'

const routes = [
    {
        path:'/firstpage',
        component: firstPage
    },
    {
        path:'/about',
        component: aboutpage
    },
    {
        path:'/admin',
        component: admin
    }
]

export default new Router({
    mode:'history',
    routes
})
```

**admin.vue(where I am trying to fetch data from database )**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <table  class="_table">
          <tr>
              <td>Name</td>
              <td>Action</td>
          </tr>
      
          <tr v-for="(getname, i) in admins" :key="i" v-if="admins.length">
              <td class="_table_name">{{getname.tagName}}</td>
              <td>
                  <Button class="btn btn-info" size="small">Edit</Button>
                  <Button class="btn btn-danger" size="small">Delete</Button>                 
              </td>
          </tr>
      </table>

  </div>

</template>



<script>
    export default {
        data (){
            return {
                data:{
                     tagName:''
                },
                modal1: false,
                isAdding: false,
                admins: []
            }
        
        },

        methods :{
       
            async created(){
                const res = await this.callApi('get','app/get_data')
                if(res.status==200) {
                    this.admins = res.data
                
                }else{
                    this.smr()
                }
            }
        }
    
    }

</script>
```

**common.js file**

```
export default {
data(){
    return{

    }
},
methods:{
    async callApi(method, url, dataobject){

        try{
          return await axios({
             method: method,
             url: url,
             data: dataobject
           });

        }catch(e){
          return e.response
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Simplest way to check what data is being populated is via vue-devtools - value of admins. You can also check the data received by the axios request by inserting a console.log statement in the if(res==200) block  `console.log(res)` and check the value in console

Comment: Try adding a forward slash to the url `this.callApi('get', '/app/get_data')`

Comment: not working , I get a waring though : it says "DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/iview.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE"

Comment: Rebuild the js file again - `npm run dev` and check if the build completes without any error

Comment: it's built successfully without any error

Comment: Now you can close the devtools and refresh the page and open the devtools again. If the attempt succeeds then you can try to verify the value populated for admins key. Or you can also use console.log()

Comment: have done,  but only message in console "You are running Vue in development mode.
Make sure to turn on production mode when deploying for production.
See more tips at https://vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html"

Comment: should I share you my laravel file by google driver ?

Comment: Yes you can do that. But tell me have you tried `console.log(res, res.data)` in the async created function within the if(res ==200) statement? What is the output in console> Have you installed vue-devtools extension in your browser? If so you can check the values in the devtools (after selecting vue tab)

Comment: I got 2 error now :Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property '__VUE_DEVTOOLS_UID__' of null
    at Object.registerApp (backend.js:1204)

Comment: and Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null
    at Bridge.<anonymous> (backend.js:570)
    at Bridge.emit (backend.js:3998)
    at Bridge._emit (backend.js:903)
    at backend.js:835
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at backend.js:835
    at listener (backend.js:1477)

Comment: Seems there's some issue with the extension. You may try to remove the extension, then reload the browser and try  to install the extension again.

Comment: ok, I am reinstalling this

Comment: I have reinstalled vue.js dev tool , and updated my post sharing the photo  (at the very last part ), please check

Comment: Find `admin` component from Filter Components panel and then in below panel see what value does `admins` have. If it is not what you expect. Go to `Network` tab and find the entry for `/app/get_data` and look at the response received

Comment: I am actually getting all data in json format in network, and I have shared the screenshot of the vue dev tool result ( at the very last part of the post) - please check

Comment: `admins` property is an empty array - not as desired. You ned to check by `console.log(res)` and see the Network tab, find `/api/get_data` and check it's response. Need to ascertain whether data is received from the server as expected or not - `dd(admin::all())` in controller - Need to find out where things are going wrong

Comment: Thanks for your time and help bro, I got the solution kevin  Izuchukwu, it's fetching data, but not adding at the list dynamically, I mean I am to refresh to see whether the data is inserted or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want the created method to be called when the component is being created. Remove the created function from inside the methods property and add it to the exported default object.

```
export default {
    data() {...},
    methods: {...}, 
    created() {...}
}
```

Comment: Also confirm that you registered the common.js file as a global mixin or register it in the admin.vue file

Comment: Thanks for your kind help! It's working after I put created method outside methods : {... } , but can you kindly tell me why It was not working inside the method : {...}

Comment: now the problem is - I am to refresh the page to see whether the data inserted or not

Comment: `created()` is a lifecycle hook for vue component, it runs automatically during the lifecycle of a vue component. Where as the ones within `methods:{}` need to be run explictly

Comment: do you have any solution to make created() run inside methode:{...} ?

Comment: You can extract all the logic inside the created hook to a function, call it in the created hook and can still call it at any other point